# How to stop a method from being called twice?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, android-livedata

I'm trying to implement Firebase authentication with Google. On sign-in button click I get `AuthCredential` details when `onActivityResult()` is called:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
        try {
            GoogleSignInAccount account = task.getResult(ApiException.class);
            if (account != null) {
                String tokenId = account.getIdToken();
                AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(tokenId, null);
                initViewModel(credential);
            }
        } catch (ApiException e) {}
    }
}
```

And this is how I init the `ViewModel`:

```
private void initViewModel(AuthCredential credential) {
    viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, factory).get(SignInViewModel.class);
    viewModel.signInWithGoogle(credential).observe(this, task -> {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            FirebaseUser user = auth.getCurrentUser();
            if (user != null) {
                createUser(user);
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "user = null");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Once I create the user, I'm redirected to the second activity. Till now, everything works fine. The problem comes when signing out in the second activity and I'm redirected to the `SignInActivity` where from some reason `initSignInViewModel` is called twice, once from no reason when `user = null` is printed out and second when I press the sign in button.

How to stop this from happening? I want to get triggered only when I press the button. Thanks.

**Edit:**

In the activity where I sign-out, I use the following code. First I implement `FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener` interface and override this method:

```
@Override
public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
    FirebaseUser firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
    if (firebaseUser == null) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SignInActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

And this is the code for signing-out which is called when I press a button:

```
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
        if (googleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(googleApiClient);
        }
```

Comment: share whole activity java code

Comment: Where's the code where you redirect to `SignInActivity` after sign out?

Comment: @ZohaibAmir Please see my edited question.

Comment: @Omi Please see my edited question.

Comment: Also, after signout, how are you navigating away? Make sure to navigate away in the authState listener. And you don't need auth.signOut() if user is null

Comment: @YashKrishanVerma Sorry, I just edited my question with the right code.

Comment: No problem, I see that you directly used override method, try using a listener as I did in my solution

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this in the Activity handling signout:

```
//Declaration and defination
private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener authStateListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
        if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() == null){
            //Do anything here which needs to be done after signout is complete
            signOutComplete();
        }
        else {
        }
    }
};

//Init and attach
firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
firebaseAuth.addAuthStateListener(authStateListener);

//Call signOut()
firebaseAuth.signOut();
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. This is the exact thing that I'm doing in the second activity.

Comment: Then please share the code where you are signing out.

Comment: Instead of directly using override method, try my solution and don't call auth.signOut after you are checking user is null

Comment: Even if I implement an interface or I use your code, I get the same behavior :(